# jQuery: how to wrap selected text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace, getselection

I would like to use the below function to get the currently selected text (source: [javascript replace selection all browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393922/javascript-replace-selection-all-browsers)).

In my case I don't want to replace the selected text but instead would like to add something before and after it, mainly HTML tags (by click on a button).

**Example:** 
Selected text = Hello
New text (html) = `<u>Hello</u>`

**Code to get selected text:**

```
  function replaceSelection(html) {
        var sel, range, node;

        if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
            // IE 9 and other non-IE browsers
            sel = window.getSelection();

            // Test that the Selection object contains at least one Range
            if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
                // Get the first Range (only Firefox supports more than one)
                range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
                range.deleteContents();

                // Create a DocumentFragment to insert and populate it with HTML
                // Need to test for the existence of range.createContextualFragment
                // because it's non-standard and IE 9 does not support it
                if (range.createContextualFragment) {
                    node = range.createContextualFragment(html);
                } else {
                    // In IE 9 we need to use innerHTML of a temporary element
                    var div = document.createElement("div"), child;
                    div.innerHTML = html;
                    node = document.createDocumentFragment();
                    while ( (child = div.firstChild) ) {
                        node.appendChild(child);
                    }
                }
                range.insertNode(node);
            }
        } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
            // IE 8 and below
            range = document.selection.createRange();
            range.pasteHTML(html);
        }
    }
```

**Code to call function:**

```
replaceSelection('<span><font color="red">hoho</font></span>');
```

Can someone tell me how i can achieve this by modifying the above ?

Many thanks for any help with this, Tim.

Comment: you taged your answer with jquery, but i do not see that you are using it. With jQuery this problem would be very easy to solve.

Comment: Thanks. I am using jQuery in general, just didnt have it included here yet. If there is a way to resolve it this way I am happy to use it.

Comment: You may want to see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24690357/add-tags-around-selected-text-in-an-element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery's append() and prepend() should do the trick.

```
$(".my-span").prepend("<u>").append("</u>");
```

HTML:

```
<div>
  <span class="my-span">Hello</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. How would I link this to the above ?

Comment: Change the `.my-span` part to whatever element you want to prepend and append. Put `.`  before a `class` name or `#` before `id`.

Comment: $(".my-span").wrap("u")

Answer (score 1):

i think this may help u

HTML

```
<div id="abc">I am a div.</div>
<br />
<input value="Add Before" id="before" type="submit">
<input value="Add After" id="after" type="submit">
<input value="InSide Before" id="inSideB" type="submit">
<input value="To Replace With Html" id="inSideRpHtml" type="submit">
<input value="To Replace With Text" id="inSideRpText" type="submit">
```

JQ

$(document).ready(function(){

```
   //for adding Before
   $("#before").click(function () {
$("#abc").before("Before<br />");
});
   //for adding After
   $("#after").click(function () {
$("#abc").after("After<br />");
});
    //for adding Inside before
    $("#inSideB").click(function () {
$("#abc").prepend("New Content!");
});

     //for adding Inside after 
    $("#inSideA").click(function () {
$("#abc").append("New Content!");
});
    // for Replacing with Html content
    $("#inSideRpHtml").click(function () {
$("#abc").html("<span><font color=red>hoho</font></span>");
});
   // for Replacing with Text content
    $("#inSideRpText").click(function () {
$("#abc").text("<span><font color=red>this is text");
});

});
```

**Check This Link**
[Here is the Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vy9P6/21/)

If this is what you need put a **Reply..**

Comment: Thanks for this. My idea is to do both at once, i.e. prepend and append at the same time. I'll check if I can get it working this way with your code.

Comment: I had Updated Some More Code on JSFiddle. you can check it by using same link or [CheckThis](http://jsfiddle.net/Vy9P6/17/).☺

Comment: Thanks, Manoj. The problem here is that it uses the whole div but i would need it to work with the selected text only. The above function will tell me what I have selected so the question is only how to combine this with your function so that it prepends and appends something to the selected text (not to the div).

Comment: hi i think i got solution for you **[Check This link](http://jsfiddle.net/Vy9P6/18/)**. if it match reply me..