# javascript text editor - how to capture selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write a simple web text editor.
what I want to do is let the user type on a textarea (or a textarea-like input) and select text with the mouse or with shift key and click a button to apply a color based effects.
my questions are such:

1. how do I capture the selection in a way it's not lost when the
   button is clicked
2. how to save the text and the selection
3. how to make it WYSIWYG

p.s. I don't want a full rich text editor. I need only one effect

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - how do I capture the selection in a way it's not lost when the button is clicked
> - how to save the text and the selection

I credit this completely to [@TimDown's answer to a different question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5393987/4639281). It replace the current selection with another string.

We create the string by taking the value of the color picker and putting it in a span tag and inserting the current selected text.

> - how to make it WYSIWYG

Use a `contenteditable` div and funnel the output to a hidden textarea when the form submits.

Here it is all together. Again, the first function `replaceSelection()` is not my code.

```js
document.getElementById('color').onchange = function() {
    var replace = document.createElement('span');
    replace.style.color = this.value;
    replace.textContent = window.getSelection().toString();
    replaceSelection(replace.outerHTML, true);
}

document.getElementById('wysiwyg').onsubmit = function() {
    document.getElementById('result').textContent = document.getElementById('#input').innerHTML;
}


// @TimDown
function replaceSelection(html, selectInserted) {
    var sel, range, fragment;    
    sel = window.getSelection();
    
    // Test that the Selection object contains at least one Range
    if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
        // Get the first Range (only Firefox supports more than one)
        range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        range.deleteContents();
        
        // Create a DocumentFragment to insert and populate it with HTML
        // Need to test for the existence of range.createContextualFragment
        // because it's non-standard and IE 9 does not support it
        if (range.createContextualFragment) {
            fragment = range.createContextualFragment(html);
        } else {
            // In IE 9 we need to use innerHTML of a temporary element
            var div = document.createElement("div"), child;
            div.innerHTML = html;
            fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
            while ( (child = div.firstChild) ) {
                fragment.appendChild(child);
            }
        }
        var firstInsertedNode = fragment.firstChild;
        var lastInsertedNode = fragment.lastChild;
        range.insertNode(fragment);
        if (selectInserted) {
            if (firstInsertedNode) {
                range.setStartBefore(firstInsertedNode);
                range.setEndAfter(lastInsertedNode);
            }
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        }
    }
}
```

```css
#input {
    min-height: 100px; 
    border-radius: 5px; 
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}
#result {
    display: none;
}
#wysiwyg input[type="submit"] {
    height: 2em;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" id="wysiwyg">
    <div id="input" contenteditable="true"></div>
    <textarea name="result" id="result"></textarea>
    <input type="color" id="color" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: thanks again. the new one deems not to work on both chrome and firefox

Comment: This will create nested span tags. Instead, it should update existing styling in the span.

Answer (score 1):

> how do I capture the selection in a way it's not lost when the button is clicked

You can get the selected text by using [`window.getSelection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection) method.

> how to save the text and the selection

Save it in a variable.

Ex: `var selection = window.getSelection().toString();`

> how to make it WYSIWYG

You can perform different actions like bolding, underlining or italizing the text (*and many other actions*) by using [`window.execCommand`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) method.

I created a simple wysiwyg editor which does bold, underline and italic the selected text.

[Check it here](https://github.com/venkateshwar/Green-text-editor).